# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableUtils.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-build

I just updated my support library from 23.0.0 to 23.1.0 and now when I build the project, I get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableUtils.class
```

Here is my app level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.galleri5.android'
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

What am I getting this error? I want to use the latest version of support library. How can I fix this issue? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult) SO thread and the solution didn't work. It gave more errors in my codebase. Also, I am not using JARs. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Cleaning the project should help And set `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: tried that. still getting the same error.

Comment: In terminal execute in root project folder:

./gradlew clean      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968171/android-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug-failed-zipexception-dupli

Comment: yeah, it works now. Thanks. cleaning the project works.

Comment: I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug) help you...

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem in my React Native Android project, and this is what made it work for me:

```
cd android

./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the exclude group: on your support V7 like this one:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+' ) {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```